# Expected declaration or statement at end of input. I counted the correct amount of brackets

Tags: c, switch-statement, syntax-error, program-entry-point

I checked the internet before posting this question, and the answer that i found was that i might have missing brackets.

```
int main (void) {

int input = 0;

while(input != 3) {

    printf("Please select an implementation :"
            "\n1. Linked list implementation"
            "\n2. Ring buffer implementation"
            "\n3. Exit");

    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&input);

    switch(input) {

    case 1: printf("Linked List");
    break;

    case 2: printf("Ring Buffer");
    break;

    case 3: printf("Goodbye!");
    break;
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

I removed all the code inside the cases to make it all shorter, but i still get the error. More specifically :

At the line of `int main(void) {` I get the error

```
'main' is normally a non-static function [-Wmain]
```

At the line of the final `}` I get the error :

```
expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

I tried clean and refresh, building the project again and i also restarted the computer but nothing changed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Given that your `.c` file is perfect, I have seen this before, the error must be in one of your header (`.h`) files.

Comment: @iharob, that's won't fix it. he has an error in one of his own .h files

Comment: i had #include stdio.h haha Ill look through my header file thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3160152: Please update your question to show your actual code, including any `#include` directives.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is that you probably declared main in some other file, whereas the compiler only expects it to exist in your .c file. You may also want to consider using a default case in your switch statement.